# Build/Publish a web .netcore api : I can't access any of my endpoints they returns 500 from postman

Tags: c#, .net-core, release, webapi, dev-to-production

I have a .net 5.0 web api application. I want to publish build it to run it on a  windows server 2019.

I build it locally in commandline using "dotnet run --launch-profile CMDLINE"
CMDLINE is one of my profile in my launchSettings.json

[image: launchsettings.json]

I then try to publish my app with the following command.

[image: dotnet publish]

I then try "dotnet application.dll"
in an attempt to run the dll localy.
the application seems to be started but when I try to access my public endpoint (returning a string with tag [Anonymous] doesn't require authentication, then I get the error 500 in postman
[image: dotnet application.dll]
[image: postman result]

My project is always compiling in /debug/net5.0/ or in /debug/net5.0/publish/

Am I missing an essential step please help. I basically want to give my build/released application  to my system admin, which is going to publish the API on a windows server 2019.

He just told me that running "dotnet application.dll" is not working as expected.
(never publish an app on a custom server like this before, always used online hosting.)

Comment: To use the correct launch profile you'll need to actually run your application with it specified, like `dotnet youFile.dll --launch-profile CMDLINE`, command line args aren't compiled into the binary, plus `dotnet publish` actually also compiles your application before spitting out the binary, it doesn't use the pre-compiled debug binaries

Comment: Thanks for your comment you actually pushed me towards the solution! I tried your command and I noticed my hosting environment wasn't the same as my specified ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable! I simply set it up with "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging" and built it up and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally noticed my hosting environment wasn't the same as my specified ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in my launchsettings.json!
[image: cmd line startup command]

[image: launchsetting]

I simply specified my hosting environment in commandline with "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging" and built it up with "dotnet application.dll --launch-profile CMDLINE" and it worked. "dotnet application.dll" is also working.